# Use a filepath for angular.json configuration

Tags: json, angular, build, config, environment

I have few different configurations for different environments and clients in my angular.json file.

My question is, if there is a way to, instead of typing all the configurations inside angular.json, specify just the file path to json file for each specific configuration?

Comment: In an angular app you have one `angular.json` even if you have multiple projects in it.

Comment: What I want to do is to specify in angular.json paths to different configurations, let's say client.config.json, que not to create multiple angular.json files

Answer (score 1):

An approach for this is to create an `npm` script that updates the `angular.json` with the required configurations

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "config:angular": "node config-angular.js"

}

// on the command line
npm run config:angular -- --config=client
```

In your `config-angular.js` file you'd read the arguments e.g. `--config=client` - here's a good article to follow for the arguments: [Pass arguments from the command line to a Node script](https://dev.to/flaviocopes/pass-arguments-from-the-command-line-to-a-node-script-1kmn)

You can then update the `angular.json` with the contents of an imported `client-config.js` file (or whatever the configs are names). There's a lot of helper `npm` modules for reading and writing to and from JS/JSON files

If you're taking this approach it's a good idea to write a unit test for `config-angular.js`, and also to output a backup of the angular.json file before each update